# What could be meant by something "puts the tin in" someone's "pockets"

Tags: phrases

In Melville's White-Jacket a sailor on board a U.S. frigate, who had undergone a severe flogging, said to White-Jacket: "these coltings (i.e. extreme and unjust flogging with a 'colt' or piece of rope) puts the tin in the Purser's pocket". The phrase is particularly unclear, since there is no apparent relationship between the punishment and the Purser's office.

Comment: Perhaps he is still referring to his shirt being *all cut to pieces*?

Comment: I agree: meaning that he has to buy a new shirt.

Comment: 'Tin' being, of course, 19th century slang for 'money'.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the whole text there is no clarity as to the use of the phrase.

However there are a few ways the Purser can gain (tin=money) from such floggings.

Others have pointed to the most obvious need to buy a replacement shirt. However it might be possible to buy a shirt from ones "mates", or make one as per the narrator did.

A secondary way the Purser will certainly gain is if the one colted (Candy) who we never hear of again? is to die since the belongings will automatically go to the Pursers Auction (which is described in much detail). But if that was the outcome surely a point would be made later.

With such severe welts "Candy" is likely to resort to alcohol for internal and external use, again under the control of the purser. Although the story would suggest he could if he wanted, go to "Pills" the surgeons assistant.